# Help understanding Matricies with the Binomial Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given three matricies (I am very new to studying Linear Algebra and we haven't done much besides understanding traces, and matrix mulitplication/addition), and I cannot understand what two problems I am tasked to work on are trying to ask. I've attatched the matricies and problems below, some clarification would really help.

$$A:=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 4 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

$$D:=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$$

$$N:=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 4 & -2 \end{array} \right)$$

The questions: [image]

For Q11, since I know D and N commute, I'm thinking we apply (D+N)^n = D^n + 2^nDN + N^2 (since the binomial theorem mentions it), but not sure how that equals A^n

Comment: Write down the question please, instead of providing a link

Comment: Added the question image in-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** First, observe that $A=D+N$. Since you have shown $D$ and $N$ commute, by the binomial theorem,
\begin{align*}
A^n=(D+N)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}D^{n-k}N^k} \\
&=D^n+nD^{n-1}N+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}D^{n-2}N^2+\cdots+nDN^{n-1}+N^n.
\end{align*}
However, in general, we do not have to compute such long list. The matrix $N$ has the following property: $$N^2=\mathbf{0}\quad(\text{Check it!})$$ In other words, any summand that is a product of $N^2$ can be eliminated, so ...

Comment: That makes sense! I know N is nilpotent at N^2, so I can see how the third summand can be negated, but what about the terms after it? They don't have N^2 (or do they since something like N^n = N^2 * N^(n-2)? So it would just be D^n+nD^n-1N? If so that defintely makes sense and I need to try to understand how to approach #12

Comment: Correct! Then you are closer to the final answer! One more hint: What does $D^n$ look like since it is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: D^n = (1 0 0 \ 0 2^n 0 \ 0 0 2^n) [is this for question 12?]

Comment: That's right! Do this for $D^{n-1}$ as well and perform the matrix multiplication. What you get would be the final answer.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, D^(n-1) would be (1 0 0 \ 0 2^n-1 0 \ 0 0 2^n-1)? So then #12 is A^n = D^n + nD^n-1*N? So do I add the two matricies after multipling n * D^n-1 * N

Comment: Try it first. It would be less interesting if I am assisting you all the way around.

Comment: Thanks! I multiplied it out and got the 6th option! Is there an explanation for why n >= 2?

Comment: You are welcome! Actually you can try by plugging $n=1$ in the general form to see whether you can get the original matrix $A$. I guess your instructor made this requirement simply hoping you could use the results deduced in #11 under $n\ge 2$, or because $A^1=A$ is so trivial? :)

Comment: Got it I understand that. Once again cheers for the help it made the problem a lot more understandable!